# Prisma: How to simplify "get rows when either columns a, b, c or d match"?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have a Prisma query that looks for the user's query in multiple columns/properties. It works but seems like a lot of code. I tried to simplify it with a helper function but got caught in confusion when I realized that there's a certain recursion with nested properties.

This is my code so far:

```
this.prismaService.someEntity.findMany({
  where: {
    contractMutation: {
      leasingContract: {
        ...(query
          ?
            {
              OR: [
                {
                  joinedEntityA: {
                    name: {
                      contains: query,
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  joinedEntityA: {
                    surname: {
                      contains: query,
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  joinedEntityB: {
                    name: {
                      contains: query,
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  joinedEntityB: {
                    surnam: {
                      contains: query,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            }
          : {}),
      },
    },
  },
  include: {
    ...
  },
  skip,
  take,
});
```